# Tomcat memory increase

Tags: tomcat

I want to increase my tomcat memory. Once run after some time I get `Permgen error`. I have seen many threads on this suggesting below change.

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

But I am running my tomcat using the bleow command

```
exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh $*
```

Can any one please let me know how I can add this memory increase options in my command line.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `catalina.sh` and append the parameters to `CATALINA_OPTS` variable, like this:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
```

check the documentation at the header of the file:

> CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional): Java runtime options used when the "start",
>                      "run" or "debug" command is executed.
>                      Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
>                      only be used by Tomcat itself, not by the stop process,
>                      the version command etc.
>                      Examples are heap size, GC logging, JMX ports etc.

and you may want to check on that PermSize, it seems a little too much.

Comment: how to verify that you really increased his size ?